# WebApi endpoint not getting hit when deployed on IIS server, working fine in local host

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Web API Endpoint not getting hit, when solution deployed to IIS server

Working endpoint  :
https://localhost:44335/Api/Course/GetStudents

Not working endpoint
http://192.168.1.3:9090/Api/Course/GetStudents

**Ajax Code**

```
 function GetStudents(IsEdit) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Api/Course/GetStudents",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                $('#ddlStudent').append($('<option>').text(obj.Student_Name).attr('value', obj.Student_Id));
            });

            if (IsEdit === true) {
                $('#ddlStudent').val(SelectedSupplier).select2();
            }
            else {
                GetCourses(false);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

**Web Api Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetStudents")]
        public string GetStudents()
        {
            string JsonString = String.Empty;

            DBPROC dBPROC = new DBPROC(configuration);

            DataTable Dt = dBPROC.GetDataTable("SP_GetStudents");
            if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dt);
            }

            return JsonString;

        }
```

Comment: What's the response code from the request? That should give you a clue what the issue is.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  response is status 500

Comment: OK, so it is getting hit, but there's an Internal Server Error?  Is the db connection correct and does *SP_GetStudents* exist?  btw, as a side note, you shouldn't prefix your Stored Procedures with *SP_*

Comment: @Christain stored procedure exists code is working fine on local host and returning json data as expected , not working after deployed on IIS

Comment: I suppose you could use a Try/catch block, and return the error message and stacktrace as a string, at least you'll have an idea of what's failing.

Comment: Will do that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping the code inside a `try/catch` block, and return the error as a string.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetStudents")]
    public string GetStudents()
    {
        string JsonString = String.Empty;

        try {

        DBPROC dBPROC = new DBPROC(configuration);

        DataTable Dt = dBPROC.GetDataTable("SP_GetStudents");
        if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dt);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
          JsonString = $"Exception {exception.Message} and Stack: {exception.StackTrace}";
        }

        return JsonString;

    }
```

Comment: problem solved.. application pool authentication error.. changed identify property to adminstrator username and password.. and it works.. thanks

Comment: Did you get that from the try/catch block?

Comment: Yes .. correct  got it from try catch

Comment: If it’s helped, remember to upvote 